# Visualise pandas dataframe like an Excel pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY1qs.png]

What would be an equivalent of Excel pivot table on the following dataframe in Python? I want to see total sum of each category per weekday

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['weekday'])["1-250", "251-600","601-1000","1001-2500",">2500"].apply(lambda x : x.sum()).reset_index()
```

Comment: Yup, that's it, thanks!
And to visualise it:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
ax = plt.gca()

for i in ["1-250", "251-600","601-1000","1001-2500",">2500"]:
    df_new.plot(kind='line',x='weekday',y=i,ax=ax)